# Punctuation - 書名號 in writing a title and chapter of a documentation

Tags: punctuation

It seems that 書名號 in English is called "Guillemet", I don't know if you knowing the English version makes it any better to understand.

I wanted to refer to a section/chapter within a user manual. Which of the following is the correct one, or the mostly acknowledged one? Or am I wrong about all these:

1. `《××使用手冊．××方法》`
2. `《××使用手冊》－××方法`
3. `《××使用手冊》××方法章節`

I want to make the following sentence:

```
詳情請參考 ____ 。
```

---

Here are my researches, as they are required on Chinese SE to show my effort. (I've learned the hard way)

[《重訂標點符號手冊》修訂版--書名號](http://language.moe.gov.tw/001/Upload/FILES/SITE_CONTENT/M0001/HAU/h12.htm)

The above document is the official document written by the educational department in Taiwan. This is recommended to write a 書名(book title) with an 篇名(article title):

```
《莊子．逍遙遊》
```

As well as Wikipedia, though it didn't specify the syntax of writing such.

But I still wanted to make sure because I want to write a 書名(book title) with a chapter/section(章節)

Thanks.

Comment: The [間隔號](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/间隔号) in the online version of 重訂標點符號手冊 is incorrect (check the pdf version). It should be like in `《三國志·蜀志·諸葛亮傳》` but NOT `《莊子．逍遙遊》`.

Comment: @Stan Thanks, however, on the online page, it says "占一個字的位置，居正中。", meaning it should be a full width character, or was there an update?

Comment: If you insist on "full-width", you can use "katakana middle dot" (U+30FB) like `《三國志・蜀志・諸葛亮傳》`, but never the "fullwidth English full stop" (U+FF0E) as in `《莊子．逍遙遊》`. That wiki page of 間隔號 has a comprehensive table for middle dots.

Comment: @PEMapModder You must have not read my question, because it contains the exact same link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GB/T 15834-2011, Section 4.14.3.2 seems to be more relevant than the section cowboy referenced since it explicitly mentions chapters in addition to volumes:

> 标示书名与篇（章、卷）名之间的分界。
>
> 示例： 《淮南子·本经训》

In other words, a middle dot should be used between the title and chapter. As others have noted, the Taiwanese reference describes the middle dot character but is using an ideographic *full stop* AKA *period* character which is not semantically equivalent to a middle dot.

There is no full-width middle dot character in Unicode and you're expected to achieve that effect using fonts and glyph selection tools such as CSS' relatively new `font-variant-east-asian` property. That's easier said than done though since you first need to find a font that provides a full-width middle dot glyph and the only one I know of is Adobe Ming Std.

Also, if you have a chapter/section number, one example I've seen of that kind of labeling is at http://www.certifiedchinesetranslation.com/openaccess/rdfconcepts-tc.html#section-Literals where a section title is labeled in the form of "第4節Early Uniform Normalization". Of course, you can use 章 in lieu of 節 for both chapters and sections.

Answer (score 0):

According to the section 4.15.3.1 of Guóbiāo(the Chinese national standards)《[GB/T 15834-2011 标点符号用法](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=GB%2FT%2015834-2011%20%E6%A0%87%E7%82%B9%E7%AC%A6%E5%8F%B7%E7%94%A8%E6%B3%95&oq=GB%2FT%2015834-2011%20%E6%A0%87%E7%82%B9%E7%AC%A6%E5%8F%B7%E7%94%A8%E6%B3%95&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j69i61.651j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)》.

> 示例2：《史记・项羽本记》

i think

> 《××使用手冊．××方法》

is better. But you should notice that the dot （you can check it in section 4.14） is not the dot in English text.

Comment: Questions asked in English is better to be answered in English.